# AngularJS app is not loading on Safari (iOS 5.1.1) back button. Any suggestions?

Tags: angularjs, safari

I've ran into an issue with Safari on iOS 5.1.1 and Angular where I am doing paginated results. After I decide to leave the page that is hosting the app, and then come back to the page by using the browser's history back button.

The application is not initialized so as I scroll again, the pagination functionality is not triggered.

Since 5.1.1 doesn't provide a web inspector, I had to rely on console.log to print events that I want to see that it's executing. On initial load, I see everything ok, but when I am back through the back button nothing fires.

My usual ways of fixing this are not working. Here are the things I've tried:

- Used manual bootstrapping of Angular app
- Made the page not support caching and expire the page as soon as it's rendered.

Neither of these helped, which is why I am here asking for some suggestions. Unfortunately it's not a very easy thing to replicate through a Fiddle or a hosted HTML file so I am unable to provide one. Hoping that some of you may have experienced this before.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is quite late and I hope you found a solution already but it might be useful for others.

Unfortunately I won't be able to answer why the app is not initialized (due to the lack of code) but I can give you some tools/tips to ease the debugging (assuming you have the iOS simulator).

Debuging on mobile safari can be done either :

- with [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) and get the features of the web concole,
- or by enabling remote debugging in Mobile Safari itself, see [here](http://atnan.com/blog/2011/11/17/enabling-remote-debugging-via-private-apis-in-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, same problem here with iOS 7. It must send the DOM structure over before running any javascript. Kinda pointless...

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is with mobile safari and since it supports popstate event, you can use this event to detect when the user is back in combination with $location.path(), for example:

```
$(window).bind("popstate", function () {        
    alert(location.pathname + $location.path());        
});
```